# How to test for unidimensionality using the mirt r-package?

Tags: r, psychometrics, scale-construction

As it is my understanding that the `ltm`-package is obsolete, I'm looking for an equivalent to `ltm::unidimTest()` in the [mirt-package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mirt/mirt.pdf).

I'm quite new to IRT-Models, so I would be thankful if someone could give me a short breakdown on how to test unidimensionality of polytomous data (likert-scale).

Exploratory Factor Analysis (EFA) and Confirmatory Factor Analysis (CFA) are not sufficiently reliable in my case [(Ziegler & Hagemann, 2015)](https://econtent.hogrefe.com/doi/pdf/10.1027/1015-5759/a000309).

Thank you!

Comment: Hope this will help someone.
What about the unidim test https://personality-project.org/r/html/unidim.html